# How can I randomly match a couple of data within the same array without any repetition?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a "randomizer" in Js that gives me the possibility to get couples of data from a specific list given in one array. My goal is to have smtgh that randomly matches them without any repetition and gives me the right list based on the half of the data's number. I've found this post " [Javascript: randomly pair items from array without repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295162/javascript-randomly-pair-items-from-array-without-repeats) " and used this one, but it gives all possible couples and I want to get only the first (in this case) 5 couples. Does anybody  can help me?
Thks a lot!

```js
var names = ["Sean","Kyle","Emily","Nick","Cotter","Brian","Jeremy","Kimmy","Pat","Johnny"];
    pickpool = names.slice(0); // Slice the array at the first element to copy it by value

var used = [];
var picks = [];

if (names.length % 2 != 0) {
    alert("You must have an even number of names. You currently have " + names.length + " names.");
}

for( var i = 0; i < names.length; i++){

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*pickpool.length)

    if(names[random] == names[i]) {
        // names[random] = names[random++];
        picks.push(names[i] + " gets " + pickpool[random++]);
        pickpool.splice(random++,1);
    } else {
        picks.push(names[i] + " gets " + pickpool[random]);
        pickpool.splice(random,1);
    }
}
console.log("picked array: ");
for(var k=0; k<picks.length; k++) {
    console.log(picks[k]);
}
```

Comment: what is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var names = ["Sean","Kyle","Emily","Nick","Cotter","Brian","Jeremy","Kimmy","Pat","Johnny"];
    pickpool = names.slice(0); // Slice the array at the first element to copy it by value

var used = [];
var picks = [];

if (names.length % 2 != 0) {
    alert("You must have an even number of names. You currently have " + names.length + " names.");
}

for( var i = 0; i < 5; i++){

    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*pickpool.length)

    if(names[random] == names[i]) {
        // names[random] = names[random++];
        picks.push(names[i] + " gets " + pickpool[random++]);
        pickpool.splice(random++,1);
    } else {
        picks.push(names[i] + " gets " + pickpool[random]);
        pickpool.splice(random,1);
    }
}
console.log("picked array: ");
for(var k=0; k<5; k++) { //instead of the whole array stop after the fifth iteration
    console.log(picks[k]);
}
```

Simply reduce the number of iterations. The for loop should be modified to stop after 5 iterations instead of the length of the array (as you had in your code)

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
let trimmed = picks.slice(0, 5);
```

Or

```
picks = picks.slice(0, 5);
```

after your code.

It will trim all other items exept first 5

Answer (score 0):

with lodash you could resolve this more tidy and simple:

```js
const names = ["Sean","Kyle","Emily","Nick","Cotter","Brian"];
return _.chunk(_.shuffle(names), 2)
```

example results:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't randomly select pairs of people...  The first 5 people are guaranteed to be in the list... you're only randomly selecting their partners.

The following code randomly selects a person from the pickpool, then removes that person from the pickpool.  Then it randomly selects the partner from the smaller pickpool.  It then pairs them up in an object and puts that object in an array.

Rinse and repeat till pairs array is the size you want it to be... in this case 5

```
var names = ["Sean","Kyle","Emily","Nick","Cotter","Brian","Jeremy","Kimmy","Pat","Johnny"];

var pickpool = names.slice(0);
var pairs = [];

while(pairs.length < 5){
  var random1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*pickpool.length);
  var name1 = pickpool[random1];
  pickpool.splice(random1, 1);
  var random2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*pickpool.length);
  var name2 = pickpool[random2];
  pickpool.splice(random2, 1);
  var pair = {
    first: name1,
    second: name2
  };
  pairs.push(pair);
}
```